How to access synapse serverless sql pool data using .net REST API
I have created azure cosmos database with analytical store enabled (through azure synapse link).
I am using built in sererless sql pool, I have created couple of views to access the data from analytical store. I want to access these view through using .net REST api.
I followed the answer provided here, but when I am making REST api call I am getting bad(400) request error.
Access Token Request details:
- GET Request URL - https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token
- Body:  
grant_type:client_credentials  
client_id:******  
client_secret:*****  
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default 

Once I get then access token then I am using it next request as below.
POST Request URL : https://{workspace-name}-ondemand.sql.azuresynapse.net/query  
Bearer Auth - Access token  
Body - 
{
    "sql":"SELECT * FROM {ViewName}"
}

Can someone help to get this resolved pls?
Thanks

The error you are getting 400 Bad Request typically occurs when the server cannot process the request due to invalid syntax or bad data in the client’s request.

How to access synapse serverless sql pool data using .net REST API

In azure SQL synapse we have plenty of Rest API's, but these REST APIs are designed to retrieve, create, and update SQL scripts, allowing users to manage script content. They are not intended for executing the scripts. The focus is on script management, not execution.


Thanks @Pratik for your response. I am bit of confused, at first place you are saying there could be syntax error while querying the data from synapse link and at next statement you are saying there are not REST API to execute the scripts/query. As I using 'https://{workspace-name}-ondemand.sql.azuresynapse.net/query ' endpoint which is giving me 400 that means this endpoint exist, I might be using it wrongly with partial information though.
